# Selenium(PYTHON) how to locate element by the ID inside the element

Tags: python, html, selenium, webautomation

so i wanna create a program that will find this element, but i would like to do it by locating the element with what you see is the 'userassetid', how would i find the element containing that number in particular

```
<div class = "item-card-container" data-userassetid = "50904623348">
```

if you can answer my question as to what exactly is data-userassetid(a class, or what) and how i can locate an element by that unique number, as there are many more with different numbers, that would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-userassetid = '50904623348']")
```

It's called an attribute which you can do this to get.